# Loading data into mysql database

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a text file which i would want to load into mysql database on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.  I have entered the data into the file trey.txt and i moved the file to /tmp directory. When i move to the db, and enter the command

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/tmp/trey.txt'
into table arp_table
columns terminated by '|';
```

the output is

```
 ERROR 13(HY000):Can't get stat of '/tmp/trey.txt'(Errcode: 2)
```

How should i modify to enter these details. And can i run this from command line as a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i was having was that for security reasons, local data offloading is disabled by default , and for the file to be read into the database, it must be enabled by starting mysql using

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword --local-infile database
```

This will solve the problem and you can insert from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data fine in root folder in ubuntu after that run this command as admin:-

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p <database name>

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/trey.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
```

if  'path/trey.txt' is not working then use '../path/trey.txt'

Comment: that's what the user was already doing...